# The interior of $\{0\}$

Tags: general-topology

Given a set $U$, the interior of $U$ is defined by
\begin{equation}
\text{int}(U)=\{x \in U:B(x,r) \subseteq U \ \text{for some}\ r >0\},
\end{equation}
where $B(x,r)=\{y:\| y-x\| < r\}$. Since we can not find $r > 0$ such that
$$
B(0,r) \subseteq \{0\}. 
$$
Thus
$$
\text{int}(\{0\})=\emptyset
$$
Is it correct?

Comment: Yes. You're correct!

Comment: Looks correct to me, assuming you are working with $\mathbb R$.

Comment: Yes. but you may need to prove there is no such $r>0.$

Comment: @coffeemath Isn’t it obvious that $\{x:|x|<r\}\supset \{0\}$ for all $r\gt 0$ though?

Comment: @Divide1918 The condition for interior is B(0,r)⊆{0}.In your comment you have reversed the containment, resulting in something which is irrelevant for the definition of interior.

Comment: Very little mistake: the definition of $B$ should be $B(x,r)=\{y:\ y\in E \wedge | y-x\| < r\}$ where $E$ is the topological space with which you are working. What you are trying to prove won't work if $E=\Bbb Z$ for instance. While Kenta S has already  commented about this, I think it's worth insinsting a bit.

Comment: After all, we don't know, $E$ might even be $\{0\}$. Somewhat related: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subspace_topology

Comment: @coffeemath Read more carefully, I also changed “we can not find $r\gt0$” to “for all $r\gt 0$”. I’m also implicitly assuming we are working in a “good enough” ambient space.

Comment: @Divide1918 Your comment I responded to was: "Isn’t it obvious that {x:|x|<r}⊃{0}
 for all r>0
 though?" The condition for x to be an interior point of the set is that for some $r>0$ we have $\{x:|x|<r\}\subset {0}$ which is the reverse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not quite, the devil is in details. You did not define what normed space you are working with. In particular if $V=\{0\}$ then it has only one point and $B(0,r)=\{0\}$ for any $r>0$. And in fact $int(\{0\})=\{0\}$.

This conclusion

> Since we can not find $r > 0$ such that
> $$
> B(0,r) \subseteq \{0\}. 
> $$

is only true if every $B(0,r)$ contains some point except for $0$. Meaning for any $r>0$ there is $v\in V$ such that $0<\lVert v\rVert<r$. In the case of normed spaces, if there is a non-zero $w\in V$, then indeed we can find such $v$ as above: for example $v:=\frac{r}{\lVert w\rVert+1}w$.

And therefore the conclusion is correct for a non-trivial $V$ only.

Answer (score 2):

It is impossible to answer your question because of missing details. Although you do not say it explicitly, it is quite clear that you work with a                       normed linear space $(X, \lVert - \rVert)$. You do not say whether the ground field of $X$ is $\mathbb R$ or $\mathbb C$ - but that is irrelevant.

If $\dim X = 0$ (which means $X= \{0\}$), you get $B(0,r) = \{0\}$ for all $r > 0$. Therefore $\operatorname{int} \{0\} = \{0\} \ne \emptyset$.

If $\dim X > 0$, then you get in fact $\operatorname{int} \{0\} = \emptyset$. To see this, choose any $\xi \in X \setminus \{0\}$. For each $r > 0$ let $\eta = \frac{r\xi}{2\lVert \xi \rVert}$. Then $\eta \in B(0,r)$ because $\lVert \eta - 0 \rVert = \frac{r}{2} < r$. Since $\eta \ne 0$, you see that $B(0,r) \not\subset  \{0\}$.